# Format string with undefined number of arguments

Tags: java, string, arguments, formatter

Is it possible to create in java something like this `someFunction("%s, %s, %s", 1, true, "qwe");` where result should be `1 true qwe`?

I tried it with different approaches such as using `PrintStream` and some other classes but I can't figure out how to do it.

So far one things that seem certain is the definition:

```
public static String prepare(String format, Object... arguments) {
    return ???
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it past that. Can you give me some advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is meant for

```
String.format("%s, %s, %s", 1, true, "666");
```

In your case,

```
return String.format(format, arguments);
```

Comment: I feel stupid now... I don't know why I didn't realise there is such a thing built-in in the String class...

Comment: @NewProger - Happens to everybody. No issues! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`String.format`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
public static String prepare(String format, Object... arguments) {
    // do same sanity checks if needed
    return String.format(format, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what `String.format` does, but I assume that you know that already, and would like to build your own function.

The header of the function that you have is correct. Now you need to make a counter `count` initially set to zero, create a `StringBuilder`, and run a loop that scans the `format` string.

When your loop encounters a character other than the `'%'`, append that character to the `StringBuilder`. Otherwise, check the next character for a format that your program recognizes, and grab the object at the position `count` from the `arguments` array. Format the object as required, and append the result to `StringBuilder`; increment `count`.

Once the loop is over, `StringBuilder` contains the result string that you return to the callers.

Of course this is only a skeleton of the algorithm. A real implementation needs to take care of many other important things, such as

- Checking that the `count` in the loop does not advance past the end of the `arguments` array
- Checking that the final `count` is not less than the number of objects in the `arguments`
- Checking that the format specifier can be applied to the object from the `arguments` array

and so on.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, that is certainly very useful. But it turns out I can actually use standard String.Format() wrapped into my own function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is exactly what `String.format()` does:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    System.out.println(format("%s %s %s", 12, "A", true));
  }

  public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
    return String.format(format, args);
  }

}
```